# "want to figure out" vs. "work on figuring out"

Tags: meaning

I am preparing for IELTS test, in which advanced words and expressions get higher score. consider this

> I **have been wanting to figure out** the meaning of that math term.

Is the meaning of the following close to the above?

> I **have been working on figuring out** the meaning of that math term.

Is there any other options?

Comment: I think there is a difference between, "I have been wanting...." and "I have been working..." unless the question is around the use of 'to figure out' and 'on figuring out'.

Answer (score 0):

As "working on the meaning" and "figuring out the meaning" both refer to the same process it seems redundant to use both. It's like saying "I'm practicing getting better at English". "Wanting" adds a new element - your desire, so that seems a morereasonable addition.

> I have been wanting to figure out the meaning of that math term.

Other ways of saying it, and some possible alternatives:

- I've been trying to figure out the meaning of that math term.
- I want to figure out the meaning of that math term.
- I've been working at understanding that math term.
- It's been my aim to figure out the meaning of that math term.

This is by no means an exhaustive list.